# How to convert escaped strings into Postgres JSON

Tags: sql, json, escaping, jsonb, unescapestring

I have inserted the escaped string into jsonb column of table in pgadmin.
as below

**Table name**: tbl1

**1.** In this table I have a jsonb type column named as "info_data(jsonb column)"
By my mistake I have inseerted escapped string in this jsonb column where slashes are coming as below.

| id | info_data(jsonb column) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ "area": { "unit": "yards", "value": 32.45 }, "houseName": "MyHome", "registrationDate": "{\"value\":\"2020-12-30T00:00:00Z\",\"source\":\"\",\"modifiedBy\":\"Admin\"}", "SuperArea": 51 }` |
| 2 | null |

To fix it I tried few queries like but all these did not worked:

**UPDATE tbl1 SET info_data = (info_data #> '{}')::jsonb WHERE id = 1;**

**UPDATE tbl1 SET info_data  = (replace(info_data::text, `'\"'`, '"'))::json WHERE id = 1;**

Please tell me how I can achieve the expected result using sql update query to correct my data?

**My expected result is:**

**2.** Now I have to correct this data using the update sql query by updating jsonb with valid json value without any escapped character.

| id | info_data(jsonb column) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "area": { "unit": "yards", "value": 32.45 }, "houseName": "MyHome", "registrationDate": **{"value":"2020-12-30T00:00:00Z","source":"","modifiedBy":"Admin"}**, "SuperArea": 51 } |
| 2 | null |

Please tell me how I can achieve the expected result using sql update query to correct my data?

Comment: if i copy your text into a json_b field it is all gome, https://dbfiddle.uk/MO5LmhF1

Comment: Can you please try to paste the jsonb value directly into the column without using the insert statement because insert statement is automatically handling it and removing escape characters.

Comment: No when you say you have a jsonb like column, so what do you have exactly ,  what is jsonb like?